# svn hanging on password

Tags: svn

I am trying to run a dry run of a merge and It hangs when I put in my password.

```
svn merge --dry-run  --username mpsss -r BASE:HEAD .
Authentication realm: <https://svn.ggg.fff.ccc:443> CORE SVN Site
Password for 'mpsss': Mypassword
```

I know my password is good.

Comment: You're sure your password is good? You can use it for other actions? (I'm sure you tried this, but it just isn't clear from your question)

Comment: Yes , i tried it several times in Tourtose. It looks like its waiting for something, it will stay like that overnight.

Comment: Does providing the password as `--password PASS` work? Try your password with other commands like `svn ls`. If that works, maybe try Wireshark on the https connection?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: thatidiotguy, yes I did, but I dont recall it. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be the option: `--config-option servers:global:http-library=serf`

The full command then:

```
svn merge --username mpsss --password password --no-auth-cache
          --config-option servers:global:http-library=serf
          --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
```